# Reactively add class after Session changes

Tags: meteor

I have a Session named dropdownVisible.

```
Session.setDefault('dropdownVisible', false)
```

I have the following template / event

```
template(name="authUser")
  a(id="user-link") User Link
  if dropdownVisible
    .dropdown-container
      p This is a dropdown

Template.authUser.events
  'click #user-link': ->
    if Session.equals('dropdownVisible',false)
      Session.set('dropdownVisible', true)
    else
      Session.closeDropdown()
```

Whenever I click on #user-link the dropdown will toggle open/close. This works fine.
Now I am trying to add an extra class to the dropdown container whenever it's rendered.
So I have

```
Template.loggedOut.rendered = ->
  $('.dropdown-container').addClass("test")
```

This adds the class the first time when it's rendered, but not after that. I suspect it has something to do with reactivity. I tried wrapping it in a Tracker.autorun function but that doesn't work. How can I have the addClass be invoked every time my dropdown opens.

** EDIT

I used the addClass example, but in actually I want to animate the dropdown using _uihooks. I just used the addClass example to make the example simpler as it is probably a similar issue to that I'm facing with the uihooks.

```
 Template.loggedOut.rendered = ->
  @find('.parent-of-dropdown-container')._uihooks = 
   insertElement: (node, next) ->
    $(node).addClass("animate").insertBefore(next)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the problem.

The 'next' argument as defined in the insertElement function is the DOM element positioned right after the inserted element ('node'). In this example, there was none, as 'node' (.dropdown-container) was the only element inside the wrapping container. Hence it never got inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that this should do it, no?

```
Template.authUser.events
  'click #user-link': ->
    if Session.equals('dropdownVisible',false)
      Session.set('dropdownVisible', true)
      $('.dropdown-container').addClass("test")
    else
      Session.closeDropdown()
```

Comment: I found the problem to make your example work. When I wrap the addClass in a setTimeout function with a small delay, the class does get added.